# Memory leak in my SharpDX application

Tags: c#, memory, directx, sharpdx

This code runs every 100 ms. The memory usage just keeps increasing until it hits 1.5 GB and then it crashes.

```
void takeScreenShot()
{
    Surface s;
    s = CaptureScreen(); 
    pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(Surface.ToStream(s, ImageFileFormat.Bmp));
    s.Dispose();
}

public Surface CaptureScreen()
{
    int width = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
    int height = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;
    Device device = new Device(new Direct3D(), 0, DeviceType.Hardware, IntPtr.Zero, CreateFlags.HardwareVertexProcessing, new PresentParameters(width, height));
    DisplayMode disp = device.GetDisplayMode(0);
    Surface s = Surface.CreateOffscreenPlain(device, disp.Width, disp.Height, Format.A8R8G8B8, Pool.Scratch);
    device.GetFrontBufferData(0, s);
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Is it not possible to reuse some of the objects within the `CaptureScreen` method? Like `Device` and `Surface`? What happens when it crashes? Do you get an exception or some other sort of feedback?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding memory leaks in a managed Win8 metro app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9995164/finding-memory-leaks-in-a-managed-win8-metro-app)

Comment: if (pictureBox1.Image != null) pictureBox1.Image.Dispose();

Comment: @HansPassant `pictureBox1.Image.Dispose()`, but otherwise this would have been my guess too.

Answer (score 5):

You are creating a new device every time.

You should create the device only once, create it in your startup code once and then keep using it.

Furthermore I suspect a memory leak in `Surface.ToStream()` the returned stream probably needs disposing too.

```
       var stream = Surface.ToStream(s, ImageFileFormat.Bmp);
       pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(stream);
       stream.Dispose();
```

As Hans Passant mentioned, `Bitmap` needs disposing as well.

You can very easily debug memory leaks in SharpDX by a helper to make diagnostic about unreleased COM resources. Setup at the beginning of your application this variable:

```
SharpDX.Configuration.EnableObjectTracking = true;
```

When your application exit, It will a print a report of COM objects that were not properly released with the stacktrace. The class behind this is [ObjectTracker](http://sharpdx.org/documentation/api/t-sharpdx-diagnostics-objecttracker).

`ObjectTracker.ReportActiveObjects()` can be called to print the currently used resources at runtime (even with stack trace).

Comment: I can confirm that the Surface.ToStream() is leaking memory but how do i dispose the returned stream?

Comment: see my edit, I think you are missing some basic concepts

Comment: `var`'s just a compiler keyword, there's no such thing as "var stream".

Comment: @Shiro I recommend to switch to SharpDx it is actively maintained

Comment: @thumbmunkeys I tried using this and their ["ScreenCapture"](https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX-Samples/tree/master/Desktop/Direct3D11.1/ScreenCapture) example, but I got some runtime errors because of my graphic card drivers (according to a forum) and I can't get it to work

Comment: @Shiro can you post the forum link? As SharpDX is just a directx wrapper, I'd be surprised if it would work with SlimDX if the problem is your card

Comment: @thumbmunkeys This is the [error](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/a0424776e6eb72bc409ad93514110d36df2d39ee/687474703a2f2f692e737461636b2e696d6775722e636f6d2f47345354712e706e67) I get and here is the [link](http://sharpdx.org/forum/4-general/3417-type-initializer-exception-with-2-5-0-full-installer) to the forum talking about the error. (You can google `[0x887A0004], Module: [SharpDX.DXGI]`)

Comment: @Shiro this error indicates that your graphics card doesn't support a feature: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509553%28v=vs.85%29.aspx It is not related to SharpDX

Comment: @thumbmunkeys I am trying to make a video screen capture program and my graphics card is a Radeon R7 260X which is probably what the average user has or higher. I find it really strange that this graphics card is missing a feature. SharpDX doesn't provide any generic way to capture the screen ? Its so much work to go through the documentation and figure out how to do it. I mean, all there should be to it is copy the data of the back buffer to a bitmap. At least that's what I think it should be.

Comment: @Shiro graphics card drivers are up to date?