# Check if data reader returns null when parsing as double

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Hi everyone I have a problem with the input string, I think I know the cause of this problem but I can't resolve it.

I have a database ,I'm using  a request that return `null` ,because the table is empty. The `null` I return it as a double. So i want to make a condition that verify if it is null or not.

This is my method:

```
 public static double CREDIT()
    {
        double Total;
        try
        {
            CLSERVICES.CON.Open();
            string req = "select SUM(F.Reste)from RELATION as R , Facture as F where R.NRelation = F.Relation";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(req, CLSERVICES.CON);
            SqlDataReader dr;
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.Read())
            {
                Total= double.Parse(dr.GetValue(0).ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                Total= 0;
            }
            dr.Close();
            CLSERVICES.CON.Close();
            return Total;
        }
        catch (SqlException E)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(E.Message, "<!!!>", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You really really need to put some `using` statements around your objects to ensure you don't get memory leaks

Comment: `GetValue()` will return `object` that may be `null` or `DbNull`. You need to test for these before calling `ToString()` and certainly before attempting a cast to `double`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Data Reader - handling Null column values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1772025/sql-data-reader-handling-null-column-values)

Comment: `Total= double.Parse(dr.GetValue(0).ToString());` => is this really returning numeric value? `double.Parse` will throw error if the parsed string is not numeric or decimal representation.

Comment: the dr.getvalue(0) is null for now , because the table is empty .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

your problem comes from not checking for null in this line :

```
Total= double.Parse(dr.GetValue(0).ToString());
```

dr.GetValue(0) could be null or not even a double so you could do something like this:

```
var val = dr.GetValue(0);

if ( val != null )
{
    Double.TryParse(val.ToString(), out Total);
}
```

Comment: There's not point using TryParse and checking for null. Also what happens if TryParse fails here? You never check the result.

Comment: @T.Wassim I would strongly recommend that you look at this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46663456/542251) it handles this in a much cleaner way and addresses many of the other issues in your code like the lack of `using`s.

Comment: @liam i m trying to write the code as zohar says , and for this answer i use an else to make total =0 and it solved there is no problem att my app now 
thanks for ur help :) :D

Comment: Ok @T.Wassim but your code suffers from [memory leaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020814/memory-leaks-c-sharp). This **will** cause problems.

Comment: @Liam .. how i can fix this memory leaks ? .. thiis is just a methode in a class that has a destructor

Comment: @WASSIM.Tofane I'm not sure how many different ways I can tell you this... use `using` statements, as demonstrated by the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46663456/542251)...

Answer (score 3):

Here is a better way to write your method:

```
public static double CREDIT()
{
    try
    {
        string req = "select SUM(F.Reste) "+
                        "from RELATION as R "+
                        "inner join Facture as F "+
                        "ON R.NRelation = F.Relation";
        using (var con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(req, con))
            {
                con.Open();
                var value = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                double total;
                if (value != null && value != DBNull.Value && double.TryParse(value.ToString(), out total))
                {
                    return total;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException E)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(E.Message, "<!!!>", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Points of interest:

- Using a local connection object, so that it can be closed and disposed as soon as possible.
- Wrap all `IDisposable` instances in a `using` statement
- Use `ExecuteScalar()` instead of `ExecuteReader()` since you only want to get a single scalar value
- Use `double.TryParse` instead of `double.Parse`
- Break sql to lines for better readability
- Changed the implicit inner join to an explicit one

Answer (score 0):

You could:

change your `double.Parse` to `double.TryParse` (which is something you should always do when parsing a number)

and/or

test for null using https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.isdbnull(v=vs.110).aspx

This is how to use the isDBNull:

```
if (!dr.IsDBNull(0))
{
    Total = double.Parse(dr.GetValue(0).ToString());
}
```

and probably consider making your method return a double? instead of a double if it might be null

also, another thing, think about using ExecuteScalar instead of ExecuteReader

Comment: This would be better with an example of how to use that in the OPs code

Answer (score -1):

```
Total = Convert.ToDouble(dr.GetValue(0));
```

use above line instead of Double.Parse() method and that will help you out.

Comment: it returns null...this will just throw an exception.

Comment: Hey, @Liam if you are using the double.parse() method and value is null then return the exception but for Convert.ToDouble () method if your value is null then always return the 0.